# Do we have $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_0^\infty|f(t+h)-f(t)|dt=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, lp-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function ($f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^+,\mathbb{R})$). Do we have
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_0^\infty|f(t+h)-f(t)|dt=0$$
? How can we prove it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** It is known that $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ maps with compact support are dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Hence, it suffices to prove the result for such functions. I should add that this is true, since translations are isometries of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, namely:
$$\|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}=\|f(\cdot+h)\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}.$$ Besides, the result holds for such functions, since they are uniformly continuous.

Comment: Can I say $C([0,1] $ maps with compact support is also dense in $L^1([0,1])?.

Comment: @Parisina Sure, it also works!